# Disable direct access to php file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm looking for a way to disable direct access to certain PHP files which contain SQL statements.

Page register.php  call action"register_sql.php"

How to disable direct access ([www.my.com/register_sql.php](http://www.my.com/register_sql.php)) and allow only script to execute code?

I have checked out an .htaccess file, but it was unsuccessful because block execution

```
<Files ~ "\sql.php$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Even if you allow direct access, then something like `<?php $myQuery = "SELECT ..."; ?>` would give no output or am I missing something? Unless you echo your queries.

Comment: Correct, but user can access register_sql.php?action=delete&id=123, in this case how t prevent this?

Comment: I don't see why you would pass parameters to another php file like that, so I guess your other php file is on another server? Then you will need some form of authentification. And if you talk about javascript executing this then usually sessions are used, but it is not enough, you also need to check if this user is allowed to do that action. Use POST and not GET then it's a little less visible.

Answer (score 3):

One tactic would be to *avoid* putting your important PHP code anywhere within the document root of your site.  This is a common tactic used by the big PHP frameworks such as Laravel, Zend, and CodeIgniter.

For example, let's pretend that your site is called "laptopcafe", and that your folder structure is:

```
/var/www/laptopcafe/public/register.php
/var/www/laptopcafe/lib/register_sql.php
```

Configure your webserver that the document root is /var/www/laptopcafe/public.  People will still be able to browse to http://www.laptopcafe.com/register.php, but won't be able to access register_sql.php.

Then, in register.php, you can include register_sql.php like so:

```
<?php

    include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/register_sql.php');
```

Hope this helps!